When should I use HTMLAttributes vs ComponentProps in React TypeScript?
I understand that ComponentProps is generally recommended over HTMLAttributes for typing React components. However, I'm unsure about the specific use cases where HTMLAttributes would be more appropriate.
Here's a simplified example of my current implementation:
import { type HTMLAttributes, type ReactElement } from "react";

type PressableProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> & {
  "aria-pressed": boolean;
};

type WrapperProps = {
  children: ReactElement<PressableProps>;
};

function PressableEffect({ children }: WrapperProps) {
  // ... implementation with event handlers
  return cloneElement(children, {
    ...children.props,
    "aria-pressed": true,
    onPointerDown: handlePointerDown,
  });
}

If I were to use ComponentProps instead, it would look like this:
import { type ComponentProps, type ReactElement } from "react";

type PressableProps = ComponentProps<any> & {
  "aria-pressed": boolean;
};

When is HTMLAttributes the more appropriate choice over ComponentProps?
